# how to modify and make labels box width fixed without changes of chart.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, chart.js, primereact

i have 2 Doughnut that needs to be aligned 1 avobe another
you can see in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JctPa.png)

the Doughnuts are not aligned as you can see beacuse the labels length is not equal.

i have played with plugins.legend.labels alot but couldnt make the legend labels width to be fixed so the dougnt wont move according to the labels length.

** my code **

```
export const DEFAULT_DOUGHNUT_OPTIONS = {
maintainAspectRatio: false,
aspectRatio: 1,
resizeDelay: 1000,
// disable animation
animation: {
duration: 0, // general animation time
},
plugins: {
legend: {

    labels: {
    generateLabels: (chart: any) => {
    const { data } = chart;
    return generateLabels(data);
    },
    color: darkMainTextColor,
    font: {
    size: 14,
    family: fontFamily,
    },
    usePointStyle: true,
    boxWidth: 160,
    padding: 10,
    },
    position: 'right',
    rtl: true,
    maxWidth: 160,
    },
    },
    borderWidth: 1,
    cutout: '80%',
    };
```

tried to play with boxWidth , maxWidth and more... didnt help
please help :)

thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `doughnuts` and `labels` into two different `div`'s with fixed `width` so that no matter the content the container's `width` would stay the same.

Comment: this is what i done ,  , but the space between  the labels box and the doghunt itself is the problem. 
i want to make the labels box width fixed , the padding between the dougnt and the labels box fixed , and the doughnt width fixed..